# What does '1 mean in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a register with 4bits.

```
 reg[3:0] a;
```

And I want to assign a single bit to it like

```
 a <= '1;
```

Apparently it is not the same 1'b1 and 1.
I am new to verilog and not sure about its syntax.
Can anyone enlighten me please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sets all bits to 1, I believe.

Comment: BTW, this is for SystemVerilog only, not in Verilog. `'1` really means fill the context of the expression with all one's.

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the original question,
To assign '1' to a[3:0], do one of the following (assuming you're in an always block):

```
a <= 4'b1;    // binary 1 in 4 digits
a <= 4'h1;    // hexadecimal 1 in 4 digits
a <= 4'd1;    // decimal
a <= 4'b0001; // I prefer this syntax with explicit zero padding
```

Each of the above assignments can also explicitly specify the range of the signal:

```
a[3:0] <= 4'h1;
```

Note that the assignment `<=` could be replaced with `=` depending on your needs.